# Manipulating DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, struts2

I'm going a little crazy. I have a slick-slider going through some pictures. 
This is the HTML output:

```
<div class="slider slider-nav slick-initialized slick-slider">
    <div class="slick-list draggable">
         <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 730px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
             <div class="images"/>
             <div class="images"/>
             <div class="images"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is what populates the slick-track:

```
 <div class="slider slider-nav">
      <s:iterator value="asset.photos">
           <div class="slider-nav__slide">
                <img src="<s:property value="webPath" />" onerror="this.src='<s:url value="/images/new/default-placeholder.png" />'">
            </div>
      </s:iterator>
 </div>
```

so struts2 iterates through the images of the asset and slick nav displays them. I'm not sure how slick nav works itself.

I have a small bug with it where the slick track (as seen in HTML output) gets the `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` property. On resize, it messes up and basically, I figured that I need to give it the `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;` property if there are less than 5 or less pictures in the asset

so I tried so many things... jQuery, vanilla js selectors, children(), find(), item()... nothing works. I can't target the slick-track class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var photos = <s:property value="asset.photos.size"/>;
//  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-nav');
//  var slick = div.item(0);
    photos <= 5 ? $('.slider-nav .slick-track').css("transform", "translate3d(0,0,0) !important") : null; 
})
```

so the interesting part is that `console.log($('.slider-nav')` gives me this:

```
> w.fn.init [div.slider.slider-nav, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
    0: div.slider.slider-nav.slick-initialized.slick-slider
    length: 1
    prevObject: w.fn.init [document]
    __proto__: Object(0)
```

and when I open it, I see the childNodes, I see the `slick-list`, I see the slick-list's child as well, which is `slick-track`, but when I `console.log($('.slider-nav > .slick-list > .slick-track'))` it gives me this:

```
> w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
    length: 0
    prevObject: w.fn.init [document]
    __proto__: Object(0)
```

As if it doesn't see it... I tried targeting it through children(), through find(), through god knows what... I'm like a step away from using Mutation.observer ... since when I log the slider-nav, I can see the children, it doesn't make sense that slick-track didn't have enough time to load... help? please.. this is hurting me as an individual

Comment: _"it doesn't make sense that slick-track didn't have enough time to load"_ JS is single threaded so if either struts2 or slick has to do some type of processing it is likely that your code is running before their code has run hence why you dont get a selected element with your selector.

Comment: If that's the case, why can I see `slick-track` in the children's children of  `slider-nav` when I log it at document ready, but I can't target it? :/ It's confusing...ill try adding a set timeout.. see what happens just for the hell of it

Comment: If you *never* want it to transform you could try setting `useTransform` to false in its options. You might be able to set that dynamically as well; I don't recall how any of it works, but I think there's a `slickSetOption` that'll do appropriate redraws/etc. There's also a breakpoint event that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @DaveNewts. I can cancel the transform through CSS with transform: none, but I need the slider to move dynamically if the user has more than 5 pictures. I'll give it a go later. I put this bug on hold for now, because I can't waste more time on it heh. It is what it is. I hate leaving unfinished work though... *sorry for the swearing*

Comment: @ChronicLogic the console's view of objects is updated when you expand its properties. So by the time you went and expanded the element and then expanded the `children` or other property the child elements were already added so they were listable

Comment: @PatrickEvans yup, you're absolutely right! Thank you, honestly. Now I just have an issue where somewhere in slick-slider, the javascript overrides any sort of CSS that touches transform. I'm getting closer however :)